# How do I make Salesforce fields availble in exact target email

Tags: salesforce, exacttarget

I am creating an email campaign for a client using exact target, http://www.exacttarget.com/. The clients Salesforce account is already connected to their exact target account. I would like to make more personalization fields (marge fields) available within exact target using Salesforce fields. Currently I only have first name available.

Can somebody explain or provide me a link to some documentation. Web searches are not returning what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Salesforce is integrated properly, then you should have a Salesforce tab enabled in the when you create a new Profile Attribute in Subscribers > my subscribers > Profile Management.

Once the profile attributes are mapped to Salesforce fields, then they will be available as personalization strings in your email:

```
%%[SalesForceField1]%%
```

Documentation from ExactTarget:

[SalesForce Attributes](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_appexchange/attributes_for_salesforce_leads_and_contacts_procedures/)

[Personalization Strings](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/)

Comment: Thanks, This looks like you solved it for me. Wish I found this a week ago.